# Python Dynamic Module Import importlib.import_module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to dynamically import python files.
Each of these has functions which should be available for execution at any stage during the execution of the initihateing python program.

My code below works okay, however I cant get these functions to be available again

Any ideas or suggestions.

```
 for var_str_file in var_lst_files:
      try:
           if ('sfm_' in var_str_file):
                var_str_file = var_str_file.replace('.py', '')

                logging.info('          %s' %(var_str_file))
                var_str_file = importlib.import_module(var_str_file)

                var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = var_str_file.main()

                do_publish(var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain)
                logging.info('')
      except Exception as var_str_exception:
           logging.error('Exception Occurred', exc_info=True)

 logging.info('')

# This does not work ;-(
 var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = sfm_process_host_name.main()
 do_publish(var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting here.  Is `sfm_process_host_name` supposed to be defined in the module you're importing?  If so, it's not going to become available in the namespace of the code that's doing the importing.  Also please post your error message as text if possible, not as an image =)

Comment: sfm_process_host_name is suppose to be the module name within sfm_process_host_name there is just a main function


This is the error is was getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_hmi.py", line 232, in <module>
    var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = sfm_process_host_name.main()
NameError: name 'sfm_process_host_name' is not defined

Comment: The module name isn't going to magically be available in that namespace either if you imported it with `import_module`.  You already assigned the module to `var_str_file` (which is perhaps a bit confusing)

Comment: okay so how would go about assign a dynamic name to the module based on the file name being imported.


I want the file name to be the module name

Comment: It is the module name.  Try `module = importlib.import_module('os'); print(module.__name__)`.

Comment: okay that does print the name as expected sfm_process_host_name but when I try to reference the main function within sfm_process_host_name I get NameError: name 'sfm_process_host_name' is not defined

Comment: I can call it like this though  

var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = sys.modules['sfm_process_host_name'].main()

Comment: I need these modules to be available within the name space using the file name it was loaded from could I load them like this?  


sys.modules[var_str_file] = importlib.import_module(var_str_file, var_str_file)

Comment: You don't need to do that.  It will already be in `sys.modules` but that does not change your local namespace.  Why do you need that?  Modules are themselves objects.  When you do something like `import foo` it's roughly equivalent to writing `foo = import_module('foo')`.  But `foo` is then just a variable pointing to the module named `foo`.  It doesn't matter what this variable is called, which is why you can do things like `import foo as bar`, which is roughly equivalent to `bar = import_module('foo')`.

Comment: so to have the module available in the local namespace something like

locals()[var_str_file] = importlib.import_module(var_str_file, var_str_file)

could be a option

Comment: Yes, you could do that if you must.

Comment: any better suggestions, sounds like thats a bad idea

Comment: so the idea is to have a bunch of singe function modules contained within a file.
Those should be available to the main program.
These are all dynamic and can change (I can add and remove modules)

Comment: How about if I just load them like this
`importlib.import_module(var_str_file, var_str_file)`

and then call them like this
`var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = sys.modules['sfm_process_host_name'].main()`

Comment: You don't even need to do that.  You don't need to do anything with `sys.modules`.

Comment: how would I run my function though? I import module sfm_process_host_name.py which has a function main()

how do I run that function?

Comment: The same way you did here: `var_str_topic, var_str_message, var_str_retain = var_str_file.main()`

Comment: I get a exception when doing that 

`NameError: name 'sfm_process_host_name' is not defined`

I ran `var_tup_temp = sfm_process_host_name.main()`

Comment: In the above code `var_str_file` *is* your module.  You don't need the module assigned to a variable with the same name as the module in order to look up functions or variables defined in it.

Comment: var_str_file as per the original post gets assigned in a loop which loads many functions

Comment: Ok, but if one of them is `sfm_process_host_name`, you are already calling its `main()` in that loop.  If you want to do something "special" with that specific module you need to put a condition in your loop like `if module_name.endswith('process_host_name'): process_host_name = var_str_file`

Comment: if I did `locals()[var_str_file] = importlib.import_module(var_str_file, var_str_file)` then that works but sounded like that was not a good option